# Oracle 12C : querying based on json keys having '.' in them

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

I am exploring oracle 12c for storing json data in a json aware clob column named `METADATA`. My existing data in that column looks something like this:

```
{
    "com.xyz.abc.key": {
        "key_a": "value_a",
        "key_b": ["value_b_1", "value_b_2", "value_c_2"]
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I were to construct a query using `JSON_VALUE`

```
JSON_VALUE(METADATA ,'$.com.xyz.abc.key.key_a')
```

then I rightly get `null` as result as oracle will interpret a different json path. I tried escaping characters but that also doesn't work. 
I went through [oracle's whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/sql-json-wp-2604702.pdf) on this topic but it doesn't cover this case.

I need help in correctly constructing my SQL/JSON query in this case.

**Edit**
 
Solution : '$."com.xyz.abc.key".key_a' is the correct way for doing this.

Comment: Did you already try `'$."com.xyz.abc.key".key_a'`?

Comment: @PeterSmith : worked, Thanks :)